# Sync files between pc and Android phone like Windows ActiveSync?

Tags: android, synchronization, activesync

Is it possible to sync files (like textfiles) from a specific path on my Android Phone to a specific folder on my pc via USB? Pretty much like ActiveSync where you connect your phone to the pc and it syncs specific files from your phone to your pc if they are changed.

I am not talking about Outlook, Contacts or Word documents, it is plain text files with a custom extension.

Basically my app makes changes to a textfile whenever the app is used, and when the user is done he syncs the textfile back to the pc where it is read by our main program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to sync files (like textfiles) from a specific path on my Android Phone to a specific folder on my pc via USB?

There are no APIs in the Android SDK for access to USB. You as a developer can do this via DDMS, or via `adb pull`, but your app has no way of initiating this, let alone for arbitrary users.